# WSO2-APIM building with modified carbon-apimgt sub component

Tags: build, wso2, product, wso2-api-manager

Development Environment

OS : windows7
WSO2-API MANAGER Version : 1.10.1-SNAPSHOT
carbon-apimgt Version : 5.0.3 (tag)

I was build product in the order.

1. i got both sources from git
2. i modify source in carbon-apimgt\components\apimgt\org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects directory.
3. build with command mvn clean install at carbon-apimgt\components\apimgt\org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.
4. i checked that org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects-5.0.3.jar file in my maven local repository was modified.
5. build with command mvn clean install at product-apim

org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects-5.0.3.jar modified file is not in product zip file.  Modifying code is not reflected.

how to solved?

Comment: Can you clarify the tags you have checked out for both [carbon-apimgt](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt) and [product-apim](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim) repos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, The compatible versions for 1.10.0 are `product-apim tag v1.10.0` and `carbon-apimgt tag v5.0.3`.

If you build components, it is required to build features as well, because `product-apim` uses the features, not component jars directly. (Feature is a bundle of component jars)